# What should be the output and purpose of this section of an EV inverter circuit?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, mosfet-driver, zener, pnp

What should be the output or purpose of below circuit (which is a part of EV inverter circuit).

[image]

Comment: It appears to be a current-limited load switch. But the circuit seems to be incomplete. Collector of T3 should be connected to Gate of T4? Please verify Source and Drain connections of T4.

Comment: Also the semiconductor part numbers don't seem appropriate. What are the actual markings on the parts?